# how can i fix this :ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, django, import, module

I'm working on a django project
as an editor I use vscode
I installed a virtual environment and installed django without problem.
I also installed the qrcode module, but the problem arises when I try to import it.
I have this message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qrcode'.
when I do a pip freeze, I indeed find the qrcode module installed,
Help me please

I tried to install it in settings.py in the install applications, but still nothing